# Is my kitten long or short haired?

Tags: cats

I have a 6 week old tabby kitten who is rather furry and i'm trying to figure out whether or not he'll have a long/short coat in the future. He's really small for his age so I thought as he's so small all his hair is poofing instead of growing out along his body lol! His mum is short haired however the dad was unknown and most of his siblings looked fluffy too, but i just thought all kittens were furry when they're so young. I googled it and he doesn't really have tufts of fur on his toes which most people are suggesting, l'll post some photos of him :) [image][image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]

Comment: I actually believe there should be a “medium hair.” I would say he is medium. I have a couple of DMH’s.

Comment: Looks to me like medium length, but extra dense coat. With the addition of longer hair on the stomach, similar to a norwegian forrest cat or maine coon. And judging from the images it looks like his tufts are just starting to grow.